# wkhtmltopdf hyperlink doesn't work

Tags: php, html, pdf, wkhtmltopdf

I'm using wkhtmltopdf to convert a html page to pdf.

I need to add a link to a word in the pdf, is there anyway I can do this?

I used this tag on my page:

```
<?= Html::a('Project Manager Profile', ['manager/view', 'id' => $value['project_manager']['id']], ['target' => '_blank'], ['class' => 'project_manager_profile']) ?>
```

but when I open the pdf, I can't click on it.